# How to open a GameObject's animation in the animation window

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, editor

I'm making an editor that automatically opens the animation editing screen, and I've created a function that opens the Prefab screen and opens the animation window tab. But I don't know how to open the animation in the prefab in the animation window.

This is the editor script I coded.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityToolbarExtender;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class ToolbarPlayerPrefab
{
    private const string PLAYER_FILE_PATH = "Assets/04.Prefabs/Internet_Player.prefab";
    static ToolbarPlayerPrefab()
    {
        ToolbarExtender.LeftToolbarGUI.Add(OnToolbarGUI);

        
    }
    private static void OnToolbarGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.Space(80);
        if(GUILayout.Button("PlayerPrefab", GUILayout.Width(100), GUILayout.Height(20)))
        {
            var obj = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(PLAYER_FILE_PATH);
            PrefabStageUtility.OpenPrefab(PLAYER_FILE_PATH);
            AnimationWindow animWindow = EditorWindow.GetWindow<AnimationWindow>();
            animWindow.Show();
            obj.transform.Find("Center").GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;    
        }
    }

}
#endif
```